# Redux-Form v6.0.1 migrating from v5.3.2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wrapped' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I wrote the same issue on https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1655 .
I've get an error `reduxForm.js:644Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wrapped' of undefined` so far when I have started migrating `v6.0.1` from `v5.3.2` .

To make a problem easier, I am now only testing only these 5 files, but still the error rises.
Please tell me how I should do.

`App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
  Provider
} from 'react-redux';

import store from '-/store';
import Catalogue from '-/containers/Catalogue';

ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Catalogue />
    </Provider>
  ),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

`containers/Catalogue.js`

```
import {
  connect
} from 'react-redux';

import Catalogue from '-/components/Catalogue';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Catalogue);
```

`components/Catalogue.jsx`

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  reduxForm
} from 'redux-form';

class Catalogue extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'catalogue'
})(Catalogue);
```

`store.js`

```
import {
  createStore,
} from 'redux';

import reducers from '-/reducers';

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
);

export default store;
```

and `reducers/index.js`

```
import {
  combineReducers
} from 'redux';
import {
  reducer as formReducer
} from 'redux-form';

export default combineReducers(
  {
    form: formReducer
  }
);
```

Comment: Why are you using redux form + connect ?! seems bit overload! try create another container for your custom redux connect! And try to use react extension for chrome and see the "html" structure. The redux-form connect should be the first parent element!

Comment: Do you mean I shouldn't use `import Catalogue from '-/containers/Catalogue' ` but `import Catalogue from '-/components/Catalogue' ` here ? it seems it also doesn't work for me here :(

Comment: Are you using react-hot-loader? If so, try if updating it to v3 will solve this issue. Other people seem to have the same problem.
[https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1262](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1262)

[https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1010](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1010)

Comment: Oh it starts working again! thanks !! XD